# How to make a input field read-only without affecting to it's CSS in razor mvc?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an input field which should not allow the user to edit. But when I make it read only it shades and all the applied "CSS" properties disappear. How can I make it read-only without affecting to "CSS"?
This is the code I have used

```
<input id="SID" name="SID" type="text" value="@Model.SID" readonly="readonly">
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: @Stuart I have used this <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">

Comment: @Stuart, this is the code in view 

<div class="input-field col s12 ">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">subtitles</i>
                    <input id="SID" name="SID" type="text" value="@Model.SID" readonly="readonly">
                    <label for="SID">Student ID</label>
                </div>

Comment: Keep in mind that, user can change the CSS using browser dev tools and update the value. If you really want the value to be not edited, you should not rely on this value from client, keep and read it in server (in your http post action)

Comment: @ Shyju,  You are correct but here my concern is about the make it visible as other even in read-only